# How can I use an objectCategory attribute on slapd?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am a bloody LDAP newbie. I have managed to set up slapd (which is part of OpenLDAP) with LAM as a frontend and have successfully configured several services to connect to it for user/group provisioning and authentication.

One service I intend to connect to this server (LastPass Enterprise) appears to look for objectCategory attributes on users, which, as far as I can tell, are missing. I can see several objectClass attributes on each user, but that's it.

Searches have been rather unhelpful. It just leads me to believe that objectCategory is something that only Microsoft Active Directory provides. Or am I wrong? Is there a way to satisfy this service's need for objectCategory attributes with slapd?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OpenLDAP has objectCategory in its default schema. Using objectClass in filter should be sufficient (when coupled with other attributes such as uid).

In AD queries, though using objectCategory in your query is recommended (as it's more specific than objectClass), using objectClass will still work as long as you specify right objectClass type.

Comment: Can I modify the schema to add it? If so, how?

Comment: why? you don't need it. It'd be easier just change the search filter.

Comment: The application I'd like to connect does need it however :(

Comment: As an SSO/pwd management software, it'd be very strange for LastPass to require a certain attribute in the LDAP database it connects to. All it cares is to retrieve certain objects based on existing attribute set - the set will vary with different directory database implementations. I'd think you mis-read their document - though I know very little about lastPass. If it connects to AD, it may use objectCategory, but if it connects to openLDAP, you should find out the proper filter accordingly

Comment: OpenLDAP doesn't support `objectCategory` in any provided schema.